# List all users and their recipes

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm writing a custom database query in Laravel for my cocktail app. The goal is to retrieve the following structure:

- User 1

  - Recipe 1
  - Recipe 4
- User 2

  - Recipe 2
  - Recipe 3

etc...

My code (see below) currently returns 3 objects, all containing a single recipe but all from 2 users. Is it even possible to build the desired structure (see above), retrieving a user and having his/her recipes stored in a array/object called recipes?

```
$recipes = DB::table('users')
->join('recipes', 'users.id', '=', 'recipes.user_id')
->select(
    'recipes.id as recipe_id',
    'recipes.name as recipe_name',
    'recipes.short as short',
    'users.name as user_name'
)
->get();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While in Laravel, use Eloquent.

In your User model add relationship to recipes:

```
public function recipes()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Recipe');
}
```

To call it:

```
$recepies = App\User::find(1)->recipes;
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get this format using query.

First fetch `users` then fetch `recipes`.
Then format them using loop.

OR

Use eloquent :)

```
$recepies = App\User::with('recipes')->get();
```

Comment: Upvoted your answer because (for now) I solved it by formatting it with a loop! Eloquent is preferably the final solution, but a formatting loop will suffice for my cocktail web app!

Comment: That's great!!! Actually, Laravel is also formatting result in that way.

Answer (score -1):

I think this would work

```
$recipes = DB::table('users')
->select(
    'recipes.id as recipe_id',
    'recipes.name as recipe_name',
    'recipes.short as short',
    'users.name as user_name'
)
->where('recipes.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
->get();
```

Comment: How will this result differently than what OP already have? He asked for recipes to be array/object.